Python sqlite3 не обновляется база данных
При добавлении колонны в бд, в другом файле, при подключении к этой бд, в ней изменений нет. Т.е было 5 столбцов, я добавил 6 столбец status в файле data.py , но в другом файле(delivery.py) как было 5 столбцов, так и осталось.
Вот data.py, там все ок
cursor.execute('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    sender_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    sender_address TEXT NOT NULL,
    getter_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    getter_address TEXT NOT NULL,
    info TEXT,
    status TEXT NOT NULL
)
''')

c = db.cursor()
        c.execute('''
PRAGMA table_info(messages);
        ''')
        columns = c.fetchall()

        for column in columns:
            print(column)

db.commit()
db.close()

Вот delivery.py, там нету 6 столбца 'status'
db = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
        c = db.cursor()
        c.execute('''
PRAGMA table_info(messages);
        ''')
        columns = c.fetchall()

        for column in columns:
            print(column)
        c.execute('''
INSERT INTO messages(sender_name, sender_address, getter_name, getter_address, info, status)
VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
                ''', (sender_name, sender_address, getter_name, getter_address, info, status))

delivery.py
data.py
Пробовал и сносить таблицу, и дебажить. Помогите пожалуйста, бд не обновляется

как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

А в самой БД новое поле появляется7

@SwaD да, появляется, если выводить из кода data.py

Сам код в вопрос добавьте. Где работат как вы ожидаете и где работает не так

@SwaD, добавил.

Вы уверены, что эти ваши файлы смотрят в одну БД? Я могу найти только такое объяснение, если один "файл" видит изменения в БД, а второй их не видит. Ну и как вариант, запустите изменение таблицы из второго файла и посмотрите, что получится и увидите ли вы изменения в первом.

@SwaD, вот такой вывод (0, 'id', 'INTEGER', 0, None, 1)
(1, 'sender_name', 'TEXT', 1, None, 0)
(2, 'sender_address', 'TEXT', 1, None, 0)
(3, 'getter_name', 'TEXT', 1, None, 0)
(4, 'getter_address', 'TEXT', 1, None, 0)
(5, 'info', 'TEXT\n    status TEXT', 1, None, 0)

Status добавляется, но не как столбец, а как я понимаю как текст в info

В первоначальном коде у вас была опечатка и после поля info небыло запятой. Сейчас в вопросе она есть. Попробуйте удалить таблицу и заново создать с исправленным скриптом или добавить поле командой ALTER TABLE messages ADD status TEXT not null
